# How can I output CSV with martini?

Tags: go, export-to-csv, martini

I would like to print CSV-data to the output with martini. Currently, I have always used `r.JSON(200, somestruct)` where `r` is a `render.Render` from `github.com/martini-contrib`.

Now I have an slice of structs and I would like to print them as CSV (stringify each field of a single struct and print one struct at one line).

Currently, I do it like this:

```
r.Data(200, []byte("id,Latitude,Longitude\n"))
for _, packet := range tour.Packets {
    r.Data(200, []byte(strconv.FormatInt(packet.Id, 10)+","+strconv.FormatFloat(packet.Latitude, 'f', 6, 64)+","+strconv.FormatFloat(packet.Longitude, 'f', 6, 64)+"\n"))
}
```

But I don't like the way I do it for the following reasons:

- It is downloaded directly and not printed to the screen.
- I get `http: multiple response.WriteHeader calls`
- I would prefer not to make this manually (the struct has much more fields, but all fields are either `ìnt64`, `float64` or `time.Time`.

How can I implement the CSV export option in a simpler way?

Answer (score -1):

Use the standard library. There is no general solution without reflection, but you can simplify it.

```
func handler(rw http.ResponseWriter) {
    rw.Header().Add("Content-Type", "text/csv")
    wr := csv.NewWriter(rw)
    err := wr.Write([]string{"id", "Latitude", "Longitude"})
    if err != nil {
        ...
    }
    for _, packet := range tour.Packets {
        err := wr.Write([]string{
            strconv.FormatInt(packet.Id, 10),
            strconv.FormatFloat(packet.Latitude, 'f', 6, 64),
            strconv.FormatFloat(packet.Longitude, 'f', 6, 64),
        })
        if err != nil {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

If you need a general solution for any struct, it will require reflect.
See [here](http://play.golang.org/p/ms5qQ1tQS1).

```
// structToStringSlice takes a struct value and
// creates a string slice of all the values in that struct
func structToStringSlice(i interface{}) []string {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    n := v.NumField()
    out := make([]string, n)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        field := v.Field(i)
        switch field.Kind() {
        case reflect.String:
            out[i] = field.String()
        case reflect.Int:
            out[i] = strconv.FormatInt(field.Int(), 10)
        // add cases here to support more field types.
        }
    }
    return out
}

// writeToCSV prints a slice of structs as csv to a writer
func writeToCSV(w io.Writer, i interface{}) {
    wr := csv.NewWriter(w)
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)

    // Get slice's element type (some unknown struct type)
    typ := v.Type().Elem()
    numFields := typ.NumField()
    fieldSet := make([]string, numFields)
    for i := 0; i < numFields; i++ {
        fieldSet[i] = typ.Field(i).Name
    }
    // Write header row
    wr.Write(fieldSet)

    // Write data rows
    sliceLen := v.Len()
    for i := 0; i < sliceLen; i++ {
        wr.Write(structToStringSlice(v.Index(i).Interface()))
    }
    wr.Flush()
}
```

so then your example is just:

```
func handler(rw http.ResponseWriter) {
    ....
    writeToCSV(rw, tour.Packets)
}
```

The function I've written will only work for int or string fields. You can easily extend this to more types by adding cases to the switch in structToStringSlice. See [here](https://godoc.org/reflect#Kind) for reflect docs on the other `Kinds`.

Comment: You should add `wr.Flush()`. But even then, the file is automatically downloaded and the approach is very manual (-> I have to manually add each field of the struct).

Comment: Yep. If you want a general solution with no extra work for new fields, you have to use reflect.